# Get contract data if all I have is a contract address

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

I have the address of a smart contract and I need to get the data residing in that address. I seem to have been struck at this for a while now and I want all this inside a smart contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract myContract
{
    address[] public childContracts;

    function newContracts(uint _id,string _name) public returns(address _newContract)
    {
        uint id=_id;
        string memory name=_name;
        anotherContract a = new anotherContract(id,name);
        childContracts.push(a);
        return a;
    }
}

contract anotherContract
{
    string name;
    uint id;
    constructor(uint _id,string _name)
    {
        name=_name;
        id=_id;
    }
}
```

So I want to get the id and name in my instance Contracts when all I have is the address of that contract.

Can someone help me?

Comment: So `childContracts[i].id()` does not work for you?

Comment: When I try that, I get an error saying ```Member "id" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address
idd = childContracts[_id].id();
^--------------------^```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sure which compiler you were using so I choose one at the high end of 0.4.x that supports `constructor`.

You need to add `public` visibility to your `id` and `name` in `anotherContract` so they are visible.

Contract names should be written out in CamelCase.

```
pragma solidity 0.4.26; // be specific

contract MyContract
{
    address[] public childContracts;

    function newContracts(uint _id,string _name) public returns(address _newContract)
    {
        uint id=_id;
        string memory name=_name;
        AnotherContract a = new AnotherContract(id,name);
        childContracts.push(a);
        return a;
    }
}

contract AnotherContract
{
    string public name; // add visibility
    uint public id;
    constructor(uint _id,string _name) public // add public to silence warning
    {
        name=_name;
        id=_id;
    }
}
```

Here's a walkthrough in Remix to show the steps.

1. Deploy `MyContract`.
2. Send a transaction to `MyContract.newContracts()`
3. Inspect `MyContracts.childContracts(0)` (first)
4. Copy address
5. Instantiate `AnotherContract(<addressFromStep4>)`
6. Inspect `AnotherContract.id()` or `.name()`

The same sequence can be done in Web3 for a client-side app to interact.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Okay so it did help but now I have another question, how do I get the data from the another contract instance without having to copy the address, like get the data from a web3 client and all I have is access to MyContracts' data?

Comment: Generally, you follow those steps in JavaScript, which would be a long answer. Consider `var addr = myContract.childContracts(0);` then `var childContract = anotherContract.at(addr);` then `var id = childContract.id();` I usually use truffle-contract abstractions and you need to get started with a provider and so on. 2 through 6 would probably be what you want in your JavaScript.

Comment: If you are using Truffle, consider working it out step-by-step with the console first, to test things, and then stringing it together in a script.